# Service Server and Publisher using same Node

Tags: ros, service, publish

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So what i wanted to do is, send a service call to this service and then i wanted this service to publish to another topic. So i was experimenting this with the code as follows. But ofcourse lots of errors and lots of problems when compiling. Please help :)

i was following the format which i saw in this link
https://answers.ros.org/question/59725/publishing-to-a-topic-via-subscriber-callback-function/

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "practice/AddTwoInts.h"
#include "std_msgs/String.h"

#include <sstream>


class SubscribeAndPublish
{
public:
  SubscribeAndPublish()
  {
    chatter_pub = n.advertise<std_msgs::String>("chatter", 1000);

    service = n.advertiseService("add_two_ints", &SubscribeAndPublish::add);
  }

  bool add(practice::AddTwoInts::Request  &req,
         practice::AddTwoInts::Response &res)
{
  if(req.a == 1) {
    msg.data = "hello world";

    chatter_pub.publish(msg);
  }
  res.sum = req.a + req.b;
  ROS_INFO("request: x=%ld, y=%ld", (long int)req.a, (long int)req.b);
  ROS_INFO("sending back response: [%ld]", (long int)res.sum);
  return true;
}

private:

  ros::NodeHandle n; 
  ros::Publisher chatter_pub;
  ros::ServiceServer service;

  std_msgs::String msg;

};//End of class SubscribeAndPublish

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "add_two_ints_server");

  SubscribeAndPublish SAPObject;
  
  ROS_INFO("Ready to add two ints.");
  ros::spin();

  return 0;
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/407843/service-server-and-publisher-using-same-node/) by [sajid1122](https://answers.ros.org/users/103351/sajid1122/) on ROS Answers with karma: 19 on 2022-10-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> But ofcourse lots of errors and lots of problems when compiling.

You should have posted those errors in the question. Anyway, there is only 1 big problem which is fixed below:

```
service_server = n.advertiseService("add_two_ints", &SubscribeAndPublish::add, this);
```

You forgot to pass `this` while calling `advertiseService( ... )`. Below is the complete working code:

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "beginner_tutorials/AddTwoInts.h"
#include "std_msgs/String.h"

#include <sstream>

class SubscribeAndPublish
{
public:
  SubscribeAndPublish()
  {
    chatter_pub = n.advertise<std_msgs::String>("chatter", 1000);
    service_server = n.advertiseService("add_two_ints", &SubscribeAndPublish::add, this);
  }

  bool add(beginner_tutorials::AddTwoInts::Request& req, beginner_tutorials::AddTwoInts::Response& res)
  {
    std_msgs::String msg;

    if (req.a == 1)
    {
      msg.data = "hello world";

      chatter_pub.publish(msg);
    }

    res.sum = req.a + req.b;
    ROS_INFO("request: x=%ld, y=%ld", (long int)req.a, (long int)req.b);
    ROS_INFO("sending back response: [%ld]", (long int)res.sum);
    return true;
  }

private:
  ros::NodeHandle n;
  ros::Publisher chatter_pub;
  ros::ServiceServer service_server;

};  // End of class SubscribeAndPublish

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "add_two_ints_server");

  SubscribeAndPublish SAPObject;

  ROS_INFO("Ready to add two ints.");
  ros::spin();

  return 0;
}
```

This is how, I executed it:

- Terminal 1

  ```
   $ roscore
  ```
- Terminal 2

  ```
   $ rosrun beginner_tutorials subscribe_and_publish
   [ INFO] [1665654555.498672244]: Ready to add two ints.
   [ INFO] [1665654646.303484866]: request: x=1, y=2
   [ INFO] [1665654646.303565863]: sending back response: [3]
   [ INFO] [1665654648.388244758]: request: x=1, y=2
   [ INFO] [1665654648.388283809]: sending back response: [3]
   [ INFO] [1665654661.012366878]: request: x=11, y=22
   [ INFO] [1665654661.012465383]: sending back response: [33]
  ```
- Terminal 3

  ```
   $ rostopic echo /chatter 
   data: "hello world"
   ---
   data: "hello world"
   ---
  ```

---

Originally posted by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) with karma: 1744 on 2022-10-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sajid1122](https://answers.ros.org/users/103351/sajid1122/) on 2022-10-13**:
thank you!